# Dual Boot Win10 + 18.04 Won't show grub or boot to

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

Installed 18.04 LTS on i3 Gateway DX4860 with Win 10 as primary OS and now I cannot boot windows. Windows upgraded from Win 7. Ubuntu install didn't detect any other OS so I manually created EFI, swap, and root partitions. Read many threads here, but cannot find solution.

- cannot get windows to boot (no grub, no PC BIOS, nothing)
- grub doesn't appear at boot
- tired boot-repair automatic mode: got grub menu but only Ubuntu-options available

Boot-repair report (second attempt):
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hSwJMp6wjS

I must have something misconfigured regarding BIOS/UEFI, but what escapes me. Appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Sorry for delay, I had to find time to troubleshoot. Unfortunately, that link didn't help. I cannot get grub appear, and Windows does not appear to be configured for UEFI. Using PC's boot menu, Windows partition isn't recognized --> grub rescue. I'm completely dead in the water. Don't know what to do other than r remove Ubuntu.

Comment: You made two mistakes when you installed Ubuntu. First mistake is new installations of Ubuntu use  a swap file by default instead of a swap partition so a swap partition is a waste of disk space. Second mistake is the EFI partition is not at the beginning of the disk. I would have created only a single ext4 partition manually and let the Ubuntu installer decide automatically where to  install grub. If that didn't work I would have tried to fix grub with a Rescatux live USB which has more Windows-specific features than Boor-Repair.

Comment: Rescatux is more granular about fixing Windows boot problems than Boot-Repair which makes it a good tool to use when Boot-Repair's *Recommended repair* option craps out.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. Do you think I can revert (remove) Ubuntu, repair windows, then reinstall (correctly)? Would this be best approach?

Comment: There's probably some complicated way of fixing it without reinstalling Ubuntu, but if I was in your position I would reinstall Ubuntu being careful not to damage the existing Windows so that it could be part of a Windows/Ubuntu dual boot.

Comment: Fortunately I have a clone of pre-ubuntu drive. Turns out windows was still using legacy BIOS boot. Will convert to uefi and then try again allowing Ubuntu to run the install. Thanks for your suggestions.